# Eliminating XAML code duplication

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, optimization

I want to have transition effects in my windows mobile application and I was able to achieve it using the silverlight toolkit's tansition effects. But the problem is I ended up duplicating the exact code in all the XAML pages.

I have provided the excerpt of the MainPage.xaml and repetitive toolkit code sitting at the bottom of the page. Is there a way to optimize this (have in one place and use it)?

In Ruby on Rails, I would have simply created a partial for that code. Is there something similar here ?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:toolkit="xyz"
    xmlns="xmlnamespace_value">

    <!-- PAGE DESIGN START -->
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <!-- PAGE DESIGN END -->

    <!-- REPEATING CODE START -->
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <!-- REPEATING CODE END -->
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up effect for page using [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

1. *Styles.xaml:*

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
       <Style x:Key="MyPageStyle" TargetType="Page">
           <Setter Property="Effect">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <DropShadowEffect />
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
       </Style>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
2. *App.xaml*:

   ```
   <Application x:Class="WpfBrowserApplication1.App"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                StartupUri="Page1.xaml">
       <Application.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
       </Application.Resources>
   </Application>
   ```
3. *Page1.xaml*:

   ```
   <Page x:Class="WpfBrowserApplication1.Page1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         Title="Page1"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         Style="{StaticResource MyPageStyle}" // Take a look at this line
         mc:Ignorable="d">
       <Grid />
   </Page>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can separate the repeating code into a `UserControl`?